lit-html autocomplete in a NX monorepo
I'm trying to setup a NX monorepo with packages and apps. The libs in packages will be web-components written using Lit.
My setup builds and runs just fine, but I'm struggling to get autocompletion working in VS Code for my web-components. It works in the context of the web-component project itself, but when I try using it in the app project I get no auto-completions.
I've set up lit-html extension and even generate a custom-elements.json.
Project structure
my-project
  |-- apps
       |-- my-app
  |-- packages
       |-- my-component
            |-- custom-elements.json

Autocompletion working from component lib:

Autocompletion NOT working from app lib:

